# Enable for Smart Displays

Tags: actions-on-google

I've published my game [Popcorn Quiz](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000b88782db03?source=web), but in the directory browser it seems that the Smart Display option is greyed out.  It is available and tested against in the simulator so I assumed that it would be available when live.

Am I missing a setting in deploy options?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's greyed out because Google's smart display will be launched on 9th October.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a smart display icon (even if it looks greyed out), then the action can be invoked on smart display devices.

We are investigating the icon color issue.